# how do I change just one character in a string when there more than one of that character?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to write a script to convert a phone number from 123-123-1234 to (123) 123-1234 and 1231231234. I can change all instances of the hyphen with tr command, but how do I change just one of two? I did the second part with this code

```
echo "Enter phone number (xxx-xxx-xxxx)"
read phone
echo $phone | cat > phone
tr -d "-" < phone
```

I know there is a better way, but I am a new student and just don't know it yet,
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Note that you don't need the `cat` or the file at all. You can just do `echo "$phone" | tr -d '-'` directly. Even if you did need a file, `cat` is pointless, you could just do `echo "$phone" > phone` directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title ("How do I change just one character in a string when there more than one of that character?") is your attempted solution but the actual problem is explained in the question body. Compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). My answer addresses the body.

---

```
IFS=- read n1 n2 n3
```

This will populate `n1`, `n2` and `n3` variables with fragments of the user's input; respectively:

- before the first `-`,
- between the first `-` and the second `-`,
- after the second `-` (including remaining `-` characters, if any).

Then you can use `printf` to print them in any format you want, e.g.

```
printf '(%s) %s-%s\n' "$n1" "$n2" "$n3"
printf '%s%s%s\n' "$n1" "$n2" "$n3"
```

---

You may want to [be liberal in what you accept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) and not require a strict format. An example as a shell function:

```
get_phone_number() {
   IFS= read -rp "Enter phone number (10 digits; additional dashes, spaces, whatever allowed): " p || return 1
   # remove non-digits
   p="$(tr -dc '0123456789' <<< "$p")"
   # check if there is 10 of them
   if [ "${#p}" -ne 10 ]; then
      echo "Wrong number of digits. Aborting." >&2; return 2
   else
      n1="${p:0:3}"
      n2="${p:3:3}"
      n3="${p:6:4}"
   fi
}
```

Invoke `get_phone_number`. If the function succeeds then use `$n1`, `$n2` and `$n3` with `printf` (like above) or in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 3):

GNU `sed` allows specifying which occurence of a pattern (in a line) should be replaced:

First (default)

```
echo AAAAA | sed 's/A/X/'
XAAAA
```

All

```
echo AAAAA | sed 's/A/X/g'
XXXXX
```

i-th

```
echo AAAAA | sed 's/A/X/3'
AAXAA
```

---

To specifically target your problem with this method, you will need two modifications in `sed`: 1) change the beginning of the line (`^`) to add the opening parentheses, 2) replaces the first dash by the closing parentheses and a space.

```
echo 123-123-1234 | sed 's/^/(/;s/-/) /'
(123) 123-1234
```

Alternatively, `sed` allows for matching patterns and saving them (by number of occurrence) by enclosing the pattern in parentheses. In the output string you can call them by their number:

```
echo 123-123-1234 | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)-\([0-9]\+\)-\([0-9]\+\)/(\1) \2-\3/'
(123) 123-1234
```

Here `[0-9]` matches a digit between 0 and 9, `\+` means one or more occurrences of the previous group (GNU extension to `sed`) and `\(<pattern>\)` will save the pattern and give it an index number (starting with 1 for the first and so on). Thus `\([0-9]\+\)-` will match one or more digits followed by a dash and will remember the digits part.

In the output `\1` prints the first saved pattern from the match (i.e. `[0-9]\+` ... one or more digits before the a dash. We then just use the three saved digit groups and format them as we desire.

Answer (score 2):

You realize you are creating a file called `phone` right?  Also piping `echo` into `cat` is pointless, you could (but shouldn't) just do `echo "$phone" > phone`

---

I came up with the following for your solution.  It may not be the shortest method but it will work:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -rp "Enter phone number (xxx-xxx-xxxx): " p

area_code=${p:0:3}
prefix=${p:4:3}
line=${p:8:4}

printf '%s\n%s\n' \
"($area_code) ${prefix}-${line}" \
"${area_code}${prefix}${line}"
```

Read can prompt the user for input so we can eliminate the `echo`/`read` combo.
Then we use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to pull the three parts of the phone number out, and print them in the two formats you require.

Note: this doesn't do any sort of sanity checking though so users could provide bogus input and they will get bogus output.